# Win Count and Loop Help (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found a basic rock-paper-scissors game and wanted to know how to create a score table for it. Also, I'm confused how to make the game last forever until the player wants to end it. Here is the coding for the game:

```
import random;

wins_history = [0]
ties_history = [0]
losses_history = [0]

def initial_wins():
    return wins_history[0]

def cur_wins():
    return wins_history[-1]

def affect_wins(delta):
    wins_history.append(cur_wins() + delta)
    return cur_wins()

def initial_ties():
    return ties_history[0]

def cur_ties():
    return ties_history[-1]

def affect_ties(delta):
    ties_history.append(cur_ties() + delta)
    return cur_ties()

def initial_losses():
    return losses_history[0]

def cur_losses():
    return losses_history[-1]

def affect_losses(delta):
    losses_history.append(cur_losses() + delta)
    return cur_losses()

while True:
 player = input("Enter your choice (rock/paper/scissors): ");
 player = player.lower();
 while (player != "rock" and player != "paper" and player != "scissors"):
     print(player);
     player = input("That choice is not valid. Enter your choice (rock/paper/scissors): ");
     player = player.lower();

 computerInt = random.randint(0,2);
 if (computerInt == 0):
    computer = "rock";
 elif (computerInt == 1):
    computer = "paper";
 elif (computerInt == 2):
     computer = "scissors";
 else:
     computer = "Huh? Error...";

 if (player == computer):
     print("Draw!");
     affect_ties(+1)
     print ("Your new tie score is, cur_ties()")
 elif (player == "rock"):
     if (computer == "paper"):
         print("Computer wins!");
         affect_losses(+1)
         print ("Your new loss score is, cur_losses()")
     else:
         print("You win!");
         affect_wins(+1)
         print ("Your new win score is, cur_wins()")

 elif (player == "paper"):
     if (computer == "rock"):
         print("You win!");
         affect_wins(+1)
         print ("Your new win score is, cur_wins()")
     else:
         print("Computer wins!")
         affect_losses(+1)
         print ("Your new loss score is, cur_losses()")

 elif (player == "scissors"):
     if (computer == "rock"):
         print("Computer wins!");
         affect_losses(+1)
         print ("Your new loss score is, cur_losses()")
     else:
         print("You win!");
         affect_wins(+1)
         print ("Your new win score is, cur_wins()")
```

Comment: We could give you the answer, but I imagine if you think about it a bit, you can probably come up with the answer yourself. Your program will exit when it reaches the end of your code, so is there some way you can redirect the flow of your program after the first round of the game so that it runs another round?

Comment: I tried using a while loop to extend the game but it did not work out (I probably butchered it).

Comment: A while loop is what I would probably use. What happened when you tried?

Comment: It kept repeating "Enter your choice (rock/paper/scissors)."

Comment: Did you put the entire script in a while loop (except the `import`)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: Maybe try that one more time? I'm not sure what would have gone wrong the first time you tried but I just verified it works. After that's working we can talk about the score table.

Comment: I placed while True: after  import random.

Comment: This is maybe a silly question but did you remember to indent  everything so it is within your new while loop? If so, maybe you could update the code you posted so I could have a look?

Comment: Okay ,it works now. Originally, I used tab to indent my lines and it messed up the syntax. Then I used the space button to indent all the lines and it worked out. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem, do you have ideas on creating the score table now?

Comment: I was thinking about setting wins = 0, ties = 0, losses = 0. Then I would try make it so that whenever the condition was met, current wins + 1, current ties + 1, current losses + 1. Then I would have to figure out how to display it and possibly make an exit to the loop.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan. As a side note, often when you have group of related pieces of information, it's good to group them together in your code as well. This helps keep things organized and is useful as you pass information around your program. For example, you could create a dictionary that contains the wins, ties and losses (i.e., `score_data = {'wins': 0, 'ties': 0, 'losses':0}`.

Comment: This is new script, but I keep getting an unindent does not match any outer indent error at the third to last self.wins(line 48). Also, I'm not sure if my score table will work.

Comment: I think if you take a closer look at that line you'll figure out what's wrong there

Comment: I changed the script again. I feel like I'm closer to displaying the score, but it won't display the actual number. It only displays the words. For example,Your new win score is, cur_wins()

Comment: When you put some text in quotes as in `print ("Your new win score is, cur_wins()")`, python will treat the entire thing as a string which is obviously not what you want here. If you look through the rest of your code you'll notice that your other function calls are working and that's because they're not in quotes. The python interpreter recognizes them as functions. What you need to do is combine the string `"Your new score is..."` with the result returned from your functions. Doing that will unmask a couple other errors though unfortunately.

Comment: Again, we could give you the answer here but I think it would be worthwhile to work through some tutorials to fill in some of the gaps it seems you may be having. This one seems to cover what I think you might be having trouble with in the first couple lessons https://www.learnpython.org/. It also is interactive so you can easily experiment as you go. I think that would give you a much better foundation than me telling you what keys to hit.

Comment: I think the sections on variable types and lists should cover most of what you're about to have trouble with when you unquote that function call. One thing I don't see them covering is how to convert between data types but I think with a little googling, you'll find python makes that very simple.

Comment: Work in small pieces though. Don't take all your function calls out of the quotes at once. Take one out, then try and get that individual to work. After that you can apply what you learn to the others. If you get stuck again, googling the error message you're getting can be a quick way to find others who have run into (and usually solved) the same problem. If you're still stuck, ask some more here :) Good luck and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your advice!! :)